# Font Selection: XeLaTeX with polyglossia and Greek

Tags: fontspec, greek, polyglossia

I am writing a document in English that contains words and passages in ancient greek. XeLaTeX seems ideal to this purpose because one doesn't need to mark the text. Loading polyglossia and choosing English helps with the hyphenation.

The default font does not contain Greek letters, so I use fontspec and load CMU Serif as it is my preferred font.

However, with these settings I get the upper line:
[image: pic showing difference with lambda and beta]

but what I want is the second line. Please note, how they differ in the characters β (beta) and λ (lambda).

I do get the second line when adding the command

```
\setmainfont[Script=Greek]{CMU Serif}
```

to the preamble. I don't understand what the difference is: my choice of font is CMU Serif in any case. Additionaly, is this the correct way to get my preferred result?

Here's a MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

% font setup
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
\setmainfont[Script=Greek]{CMU Serif}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}

\begin{document}
This is my text! This is my Greek: ἀλλὰ τοῦτο μὲν ἔσβεσεν.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why do you use `\setdefaultlanguage{german}`?

Comment: thanks for the comment. I should be using english and have edited my question

Comment: When I compile your document I get the second line you show, with the rounded tops of the gamma. Are you using an up-to-date distribution of LaTeX?

Comment: Just a note if you didn't know, some font packages include unicode Greek. For example, instead of your whole `fontspec` section of code, you could just write `\usepackage{ebgaramond}`.

Comment: thanks for the answers! somehow I had not been able to find the page you linked before.